# How do I apply touches to images, using Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touchesSet = touches as NSSet
    let touch = touchesSet.anyObject() as? UITouch
    let location = touch?.location(in: self.view)
    if touch!.view == bee1 {
        bee1?.center = location!
    } else if touch!.view == bee2 {
        bee2?.center = location!
    }
}
```

I need code this game for iOS, using Swift; but I don't know how to apply touches to images, using Swift. My attempts thus far have failed; touch!.view != image

Comment: Use gestures OR use button and apply image to that button

Comment: Try adding "User Interaction Enabled" to your bee images.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign an action for UIImageView object in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880607/how-to-assign-an-action-for-uiimageview-object-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this images are indiviudal image views, then you can simply put tap recognizer and call action when you touch it.
[How to assign an action for UIImageView object in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880607/how-to-assign-an-action-for-uiimageview-object-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use gesture and set the image userInteractionEnabled = true
OBJ-C:

```
self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapImageView:)];
tap.delegate= self;
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```