# MessageKit : Add Gesture recognizer to messageCollectionView and cellDelegate doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, messagekit

I am using messageKit show messages,video and photo in a text format and all the messages are predefined. When user taps on the screen it, should show the next message. I have added gesture recognizer to messageCollectionView but when the user taps on the image, i need to show the image in full screen. But the cell delegate is never called

```
   let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MessageViewController.tapScreen(_:)))

    messagesCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource = self
    messagesCollectionView.messagesLayoutDelegate = self
    messagesCollectionView.messagesDisplayDelegate = self
    messagesCollectionView.messageCellDelegate = self
```

I am using the lates messageKit

```
pod 'MessageKit'
```

Any idea how i can achieve this?

To further clarify, here is an image of the screen. Clicking anywhere should call the gesture function, but image should call the cellDelegate.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880607/how-to-assign-an-action-for-uiimageview-object-in-swift/53809261#53809261          -> use that tap gesture on  UIView, UIImageView and all child of UIView etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can call this method provided by Messagekit it self.

```
 extension ViewController: MessageCellDelegate {

func didTapAvatar(in cell: MessageCollectionViewCell) {
    print("Avatar tapped")
}

func didTapMessage(in cell: MessageCollectionViewCell) {
 // handle message here
 print("Meesage Tapped")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ChatViewController in `viewDidLoad` before the `super.viewDidLodad`
call. You can add:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
    #selector(cellTapped(sender:)))
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        messagesCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
     super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @objc
    private func cellTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Do Something
    }
```

Or you can use the already provided function in the `MessageCellDelegate`

```
func didTapImage(in cell: MessageCollectionViewCell) {}
```