# UIImageView change depends on its state

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I'm trying to create an `UIImageView` that when I tap on it, changes it's image, but don't know how to make it clickable.

I have this :

```
lazy var myImage: UIImageView = {
      let image = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
      image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
      image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
      image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
      //Here shall I specify the first state? if it's enabled or not? Enabled or not means enabled = Image1, not enabled = Image2
      return image
    }()
```

I'm using this image from other class, so perhaps here I do not have to specify anything and only from the method of my presenter set the image as I described :

Enabled = Image1

Disabled = Image2

Comment: Add UITapGestureRecognizer to the imageView.

Comment: This is to detect click? Could you provide an example adding this UITapGestureRecognizer and change the view depending of its state please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign an action for UIImageView object in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880607/how-to-assign-an-action-for-uiimageview-object-in-swift)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, instead of creating the `imageView` programatically, create it in the `storyboard` and use an `@IBOutlet` for it.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

Create 2 `UIImage` properties `enabledImage` and `disabledImage`

```
let enabledImage = UIImage(named: "enabled")
let disabledImage = UIImage(named: "disabled")
```

In `viewDidLoad()`,

1. Set the `imageView's` initial `image` as `enabledImage` (change as per your requirement)
2. Create a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and add it to the `imageView`
3. Set `imageView's` `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true`
4. In `imageViewTapped(_:)` method, modify `imageView.image` according to the current `image` set.

So, compiling all the above points

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    let enabledImage = UIImage(named: "enabled")
    let disabledImage = UIImage(named: "disabled")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.image = enabledImage
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageViewTapped(_:)))
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    @objc func imageViewTapped(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        imageView.image = (imageView.image == enabledImage) ? disabledImage : enabledImage
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Here sample how to use UITapGesture recognizer:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let gestureRecogniser = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecogniser)
    }

    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UIImageView) {
        debugPrint(sender)
    }
}
```

Comment: But then how do I change the image?

Comment: Change image at handleTap func

Comment: Change debugPrint to method which change picture.